# Find which AS3 classes are included in a SWF

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, flash

I have been investigating swfmill and ran it against some of my AS3 SWFs, I get

```
<UnknownTag id="0x52">
    <data>...</data>
  </UnknownTag>
```

and

```
UnknownTag id="0x4C">
    <data>...</data>
  </UnknownTag>
```

These lines are most likely contain the data I am looking for, but the data is unreadable.  Does anyone know of another way to find the included classes in a SWF, or know how to decipher the data in these tags?  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK swfmill predates AVM2, so I wouldn't expect much luck doing anything with code on an AVM2 swf using swfmill.

EDIT: Perhaps [Sothink Swf Decompiler](http://www.sothink.com/product/flashdecompiler/) would be better suited to your needs?

Comment: If swfmill predates AVM2, are there any other similar tools that will accurately parse a AS3 SWF into good XML?  Really what I need is a tool that will tell me which classes are included in the published SWF, so I can figure out the dependencies.